# c++: almost same input but 2nd call shows segment fault

Tags: c++

I've been a C# developer for a long time and try to refresh my previous C++ knowledge.
I don't know why the "root" address of the second IsBalanced(root) call becomes 0x0.
Definitely, this question will be very obvious to most C++ developers. Please, provide me some hint.

The result:
1. Is Balanced? 0
Segmentation fault: 11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

int GetHeight(Node *node) {
    if(node == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
        return 1;
    int leftHeight = GetHeight(node->left);
    int rightHeight = GetHeight(node->right);
    if(leftHeight > rightHeight)
        return 1 + leftHeight;
    else
        return 1 + rightHeight;
}

bool IsBalanced(Node &node){    
    int leftHeight = 0;
    int rightHeight = 0;

    if(node.left == NULL && node.right == NULL)
        return true;

    if(node.left != NULL)
        leftHeight = GetHeight(node.left);

    if(node.right != NULL)
        rightHeight = GetHeight(node.right);

    int diff = leftHeight - rightHeight;
    if(diff >= -1 && diff <= 1)
    {
        if(IsBalanced(*node.left) && IsBalanced(*node.right))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {
    Node root, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;

    root.left = &n1;
    root.right = NULL;
    n1.left = &n2;
    n1.right = &n3;
    n2.left = NULL;
    n2.right = NULL;
    n3.left = &n4;
    n3.right = NULL;
    n4.right = &n5;
    n4.left = NULL;
    n5.right = NULL;
    n5.left = NULL;

    cout<< "1. Is Balanced? " << IsBalanced(root) << endl;


    root.left = &n1;
    root.right = &n2;
    n1.left = &n3;
    n1.right = &n4;
    n2.left = &n5;
    n2.right = NULL;
    n3.left = NULL;
    n3.right = NULL;
    n4.right = NULL;
    n4.left = NULL;
    n5.right = NULL;
    n5.left = NULL;

    cout<< "2. Is Balanced? " << IsBalanced(root) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? On which line does the segmentation fault occur?

Comment: @cdhowie I am using Xcode for the first time. So, I couldn't debug as well as I can in MS VS IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the culprit.

```
    if(IsBalanced(*node.left) && IsBalanced(*node.right))
```

You are not checking whether `node.left` or `node.right` is NULL before dereferencing them. The first iteration works due to lucky coincidence.

Here's an updated version of `IsBalanced` that works for me:

```
bool IsBalanced(Node &node){
   int leftHeight = 0;
   int rightHeight = 0;

   if(node.left == NULL && node.right == NULL)
      return true;

   if(node.left != NULL)
      leftHeight = GetHeight(node.left);

   if(node.right != NULL)
      rightHeight = GetHeight(node.right);

   int diff = leftHeight - rightHeight;
   if(diff >= -1 && diff <= 1)
   {
      if ( node.left == NULL || node.right == NULL )
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return (IsBalanced(*node.left) && IsBalanced(*node.right));
      }
   }
   else
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be due to your get `GetHeight(node* node)` Function

Take the case `node.left = Null` and `node.right = node2`

Your GetHeight function would end up passing node->left (which is NULL) to a recursive GetHeight function, then that GetHeight function would segfault when testing for conditions:

```
if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
```

GetHeight should have separate cases for if only one of the nodes children are NULL

Answer (score 0):

You recursively call IsBalanced where in some case the node passed is NULL. For example, if one (but not both) of the children are NULL and diff is between -1 and 1. This happens for node 2 in the second call.

You probably could find this quickly by stepping through the code.